# How can I compare an unlimited number of arrays on a singular level in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to compare a variable number of arrays looking for common elements, BUT it has to be done in a singular fashion, so `array_intersect()` fails. By singular I mean that it must check `array1` against `array2` then `array1` against `array3` then `array2` against `array3`, ... etc. and end up with a list of unique elements that are shared in any 2 arrays.

I did try  `call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$stack)` where `$stack` was an array of all arrays to be compared. Again, that failed because it looks for intersections in ALL arrays, and does not check singularly.

```
$arr1 = array('temporal','disease','funny','fancy');
$arr2 = array('jaime','delusional','something','temporal');
$arr3 = array('funny','faeries','vampire');
$arr4 = array('shifty','fancy','funky','fantastic');
```

The result of the comparison should be something like:

```
temporal, funny, fancy
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So you want as many intersections as there are pairs of input arrays?

Comment: So what would you want the returned structure to look like?

Comment: @Vigrond it can be an simple array returned

Comment: @Jon basically I need a list of elements that are in at least 2 arrays, it can be shared in more than 2 but has to be shared by at least 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the values are strings/ints(valid as array keys).

```
$flat = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arrayOfArrays);
$duplicates = array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values($flat), function($numOccurances){
    return $numOccurances > 1;
}));
```

I merge all the values into one array, then I count their occurrences, then filter out the singular entries. I'm sure theres more efficient algorithms if needed, but I'm guessing it doesn't matter.

I guess this should be called array_not_unique()

Comment: There can be array_filter without callback, it will filter out values that are false like, so there would be no elements with 0 occurances

Comment: @piotrekkr, the smallest value in the array would be 1 according to how array_count_values works.

Comment: ok my bad, you are right :) So there should be `$numOccurances > 1` if you want get two or more occurances?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example:

```
<pre>
<?php
$arr1 = array('temporal','disease','funny','fancy');
$arr2 = array('jaime','delusional','something','temporal');
$arr3 = array('funny','faeries','vampire');
$arr4 = array('shifty','fancy','funky','fantastic');

$a = array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4);

print_r($a);

print_r(array_diff_key( $a , array_unique( $a ) ));
?>
</pre>
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => temporal
    [1] => disease
    [2] => funny
    [3] => fancy
    [4] => jaime
    [5] => delusional
    [6] => something
    [7] => temporal
    [8] => funny
    [9] => faeries
    [10] => vampire
    [11] => shifty
    [12] => fancy
    [13] => funky
    [14] => fantastic
)
Array
(
    [7] => temporal
    [8] => funny
    [12] => fancy
)
```

So you can see, first we combine the arrays.  Then we get the difference of the original array with that of the same array with duplicates removed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but maybe something like this can do the job:

```
$arrays = array();

$arr1 = array('temporal','disease','funny','fancy');
$arr2 = array('jaime','delusional','something','temporal');
$arr3 = array('funny','faeries','vampire');
$arr4 = array('shifty','fancy','funky','fantastic');

array_push($arrays, $arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4);

foreach ($array_push as $key => $array) {
    foreach ($array_push as $key2 => $array2) {
        if($key!=$key2 && empty(array_diff($array, $array2)) {
            echo $key.' and '.$key2.' arrays are the same';
        }
    }
}
```

You can create a function($arrayWithArrays) and it should work.